# Insert into schema.table PostgreSQL c#

Tags: c#, postgresql, ado.net

Как добавить запись в бд с указанием нужной схемы?
Проблема с запросом. Если не указывать имя схемы, то записывает в public, если указываю тогда получаю ошибку.

```
public void insertquery(string sName)
        {
            command.CommandText = $"INSERT INTO rpsql.s_test(script_name) values ('{sName}')";
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас же `schema_name` это имя схемы, в чем вопрос?

Comment: @Ruslan Artamonov, поправил.

Comment: Приведите еще текст ошибки, пожалуйста

Comment: добавил скрины.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы пишете название схемы без кавычек, оно подставляется буквами нижнего регистра. У вас название схемы в базе написано буквами верхнего регистра, значит пишите `$"INSERT INTO \"RPSQL\".s_test(script_name)"`